# Save Query result into Variable Alexa Skills Json

Tags: mysql, json, variables, alexa-skills-kit

I needed a DB for an alexa app, so I set up and and it INSERTS nicely, but when im trying to SELECT and save it to a variable the values saved to the variable are [Object Object] instead of wanted value, I know it can be async problem or parsing problem but i just cant fix the code, some help would be cool,

````
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'buscaIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {

            const mysql = require('mysql');
            const connection = mysql.createConnection
            ({
            host: 'remotemysql.com',
            user: 'RBb34534sd',
            password: 'xxxxxxxxx',
            database: 'RBsdfewrg'
            });


            var stat = connection.query('SELECT `spe` FROM `prueba` WHERE `nombre` LIKE "raichu" limit 1', function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
                return result[0];
              });
            connection.end();

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder

            .speak("Busc " + stat)
            .reprompt("reprompt buscar")
            .getResponse();


    }
}; ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're not waiting for your database query to complete before sending your response to the Alexa service. Requests in node.js are non-blocking, meaning you either need to nest the request with a callback, or leverage Promises / async-await patterns so that the SQL query is processed before the function is fully executed.

You can read more on converting the built-in library for SQL connections to support Promises [here](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-async-await-6fb25b01b628), or use a library like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) that already has a wrapper in place.

In either scenario, the end result would be refactored to something like this:

```
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
        && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'buscaIntent';
},
async handle(handlerInput) {
        const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
        const connection = await mysql.createConnection
        ({
        host: 'remotemysql.com',
        user: 'RBb34534sd',
        password: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        database: 'RBsdfewrg'
        });

        var stat = await connection.execute('SELECT `spe` FROM `prueba` WHERE `nombre` LIKE "raichu" limit 1', function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            return result[0];
          });

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak("Busc " + stat)
        .reprompt("reprompt buscar")
        .getResponse();
}
```

Another article describing async calls for Alexa requests [here](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/4a46da08-d1b8-4d8e-9277-055307a9bf4a/alexa-skill-recipe-update-call-and-get-data-from-external-apisblog).

Comment: Hey I tried to place at package  **"mysql2-promise": "^3.1.1"**  for getting this to work, but i keep having this error so i did it wrong...  **Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2-promise'**

Answer (score 0):

I think the query is returning an object you can't keep the object in speech. Check what's inside the object and if you have a field that you want inside that object then access by `stat.YourField`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, i saw this log
`16:15:47
2019-12-30T16:15:47.346Z 606a3f88-b17d-499b-bd70-0e5ba140b496 [ RowDataPacket { spe: 777 }`   when the query runs, but Trying `.speak("Busc " + stat.spe)` gets me Undefined instead of [Object Object]

Comment: I think it is in array right if you have only one element then access it by ``stat[0].RowDataPacket.spe`` or else you have to iterate that array and get the value you want.